# I am receiving a syntax error every time I write an if statement on python, any ideas?

Tags: python

I am a total beginner working on an introductory python class but I am getting syntax errors every time I make an if statement.  Can anyone help with this?
Here is my code:

```
def report_size(n: int) -> str:
    """Return 'small' if n is between 0 and 20 inclusive,
    'medium' if n is between 21 and 40 inclusive,
    and 'large' if n is 41 or greater.
    
    Precondition: n >= 0
    
    >>> report_size(4)
    'small'
    >>> report_size(24)
    'medium'
    >>> report_size(45)
    'large'
    """
    If n <= 20:
        return 'small"
    elif 20< n <= 40:
        return 'medium"
    else:
        return 'large'
```

Comment: Check how you declare your string. This looks like a typo.

Comment: you have a typo in If. it is supposed to be lowercase ```if```

Answer (score 2):

`if` should not be capitalized.

Also, the apostrophes you use for strings are inconsistent. If you open a string with `'` you have to close with `'` and if you open with `"` you should close the string with `"`.

Comment: Questions caused by typos should not be answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, and the link therein to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, which lists questions "caused by simple typographical error" among the classes that are categorically off-topic.